# Combining two subgroups of data in the same dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = data.frame(time=c(2010:2015,2010:2015),
                variable=c(rep("a",6),rep("b",6)),
                value=c(rnorm(6),rnorm(6,mean=10)))
```

or:

```
   time variable      value 
1  2010        a -0.5472416
...
6  2015        a -0.2433123
7  2010        b  9.8617777
... 
12 2015        b  7.7674609
```

I need to create a new variable 'c=a-b'. The best solution I've found is to use packages 'dplyr' and 'tidyr':

```
df <- spread(df,variable,value) %>% 
      mutate(c=b-a) %>% 
      gather(variable,value,a:c) %>%
      filter(variable=="c")
```

which gives the requested outcome:

```
  time variable      value
1 2010        c  10.444794
2 2011        c   8.121627
...
6 2015        c  10.589378
```

Is there a more direct way to obtain the same result, which does not require first to "spread" and then to "gather" the dataframe?

Comment: Are the values within `a` and `b` always in the same order (in terms of subtracting the first `a` from the first `b`, second `a` from the second `b`, and so on)?

Comment: usually they are (and they are in the example), but I cannot rule out the case that some years are missing

Comment: Do the `a`s always come before the `b`s in the data frame?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `group_by` and `summarize`:

```
c <- df %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    summarize(value = diff(value))
```

Note that this assumes the `a`s come before the `b`s in the data frame. If you're not sure, you can add an `arrange(variable)` before the `group_by`.

If one variable could have years that aren't in the other (as in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151717/combining-two-subgroups-of-data-in-the-same-dataframe/30151878#comment48410842_30151717)), you could get rid of those cases by adding an extra step:

```
c <- df %>%
    group_by(time) %>%
    filter(n() == 2) %>%
    summarize(value = diff(value))
```

Comment: That will work only under the assumption that `b` is always after `a`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know. I asked about that [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151717/combining-two-subgroups-of-data-in-the-same-dataframe/30151878#comment48410974_30151717) and added an optional solution.