# How to make data in a single column (long) with multiple, nested group categories wide

Tags: r, tidyr

I've got a mess of data and am trying to efficiently wrangle it into shape. Here's a simplified short sample of the general format of my data.frame right now.  The main difference is that I have a few more data labels like `Label1` for my sampling units - each has a set of data similar to the data.frame I'm including but in my situation they are all in the same data.frame.  I don't think that will complicate the reformatting so I've just included the single sampling unit of mock data here.  `StatsType` levels `Ave`, `Max`, and `Min` are effectively nested within `MeasureType`.

```
tastycheez<-data.frame(
  Day=rep((1:3),9),
  StatsType=rep(c(rep("Ave",3),rep("Max",3),rep("Min",3)),3),
  MeasureType=rep(c("Temp","H2O","Tastiness"),each=9),
  Data_values=1:27,
  Label1=rep("SamplingU1",27))
```

Ultimately, I would like a data frame where for each sampling unit and each `Day` there are columns holding the `Data_values` for my categories, like this:

```
 Day     Label1   Ave.Temp Ave.H2O Ave.Tastiness  Max.Temp ...
 1   SamplingU1          1      10            19         4 ...
 2   SamplingU1          2      11            20         5 ...
```

I think some combination of functions from `reshape`,`dplyr`,`tidyr`, and/or `data.table` could do the job but I can't figure out how to code it. Here's what I've tried:

First, I `spread` the `tastycheez` (yum!), and that got me partway:

```
test<-spread(tastycheez,StatsType,Data_values)
```

Now I'm trying to `spread` it again or to `cast`, but with no luck:

```
test2<-spread(test,MeasureType,(Ave,Max,Min))

test2 <- recast(Day ~ MeasureType+c(Ave,Max,Min), data=test)
```

(I also tried `melt`ing the `tastycheez` but <strike>the results were a sticky, gooey mess and my tongue got burnt.</strike> that doesn't seem to be the right function for this.)

If you hate my puns please excuse them, I really can't figure this out!

Here are a couple related questions:
[Combining two subgroups of data in the same dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151717/combining-two-subgroups-of-data-in-the-same-dataframe)
[How can I spread repeated measures of multiple variables into wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775461/tidyr-repeated-measures-multiple-variables-wide-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**reshape2** You could use `dcast` from *reshape2*:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(tastycheez, 
  Day + Label1 ~ paste(StatsType, MeasureType, sep="."), 
  value.var = "Data_values")
```

which gives

```
  Day     Label1 Ave.H2O Ave.Tastiness Ave.Temp Max.H2O Max.Tastiness Max.Temp Min.H2O Min.Tastiness Min.Temp
1   1 SamplingU1      10            19        1      13            22        4      16            25        7
2   2 SamplingU1      11            20        2      14            23        5      17            26        8
3   3 SamplingU1      12            21        3      15            24        6      18            27        9
```

---

**tidyr** Stealing @DavidArenburg's comment, here's the *tidyr* way:

```
library(tidyr)
tastycheez %>%
       unite(temp, StatsType, MeasureType, sep = ".") %>% 
       spread(temp, Data_values)
```

which gives

```
  Day     Label1 Ave.H2O Ave.Tastiness Ave.Temp Max.H2O Max.Tastiness Max.Temp Min.H2O Min.Tastiness Min.Temp
1   1 SamplingU1      10            19        1      13            22        4      16            25        7
2   2 SamplingU1      11            20        2      14            23        5      17            26        8
3   3 SamplingU1      12            21        3      15            24        6      18            27        9
```

Comment: I don't know the tidyr way, so you'll probably want to wait for more answers.

Comment: The `tidyr` way would be something like `tastycheez %>% unite(temp, StatsType, MeasureType, sep = ".") %>% spread(temp, Data_values)`